# graph Ql schema using graphQlObjectType

Tags: node.js, express, graphql

i am beginner in Graph Ql.but i am trying to create a grapghql server with node and express as follow...

```
const graphql = require('graphql');
const _ = require('lodash')
const { GraphQlObjectType, GraphQLString,GraphQLSchema,buildSchema } = 
    graphql;
var books=[
    {name:'Hezaro yek Shab',gener:'romans',id:1},
    {name:'Fergosen memorizes',gener:'sport',id:2},
    {name:'Hpliday physics',gener:'sience',id:3}
];

const BookType = new GraphQlObjectType({
    name: 'Book',
    fields: () => ({
        id: { type: GraphQLString },
        title: { type: GraphQLString },
        gener: { type: GraphQLString }
    })
});

const RootQuery=new GraphQlObjectType({ 
    name:'RootQueryType',
    fields:{
        book:{
            type:BookType,
            args:{ id: { type: GraphQLString }},
            resolve(parent,args){
               return _.find(books,{id:args.id});
            }
        }
    },

});
module.exports=new GraphQLSchema({
    query:RootQuery
});
```

i used GraphQlObjectType to create schema for book and for Root Query and then passed book type into Root Query type as well . 
any way i want to find particular book in array of books (data dont come from database at this time -just from local array)

but i have this error
[image]

Comment: Could you try console GraphQlObjectType

Comment: yoooop . i fixed it
we should use GraphQLObjectType instead of GraphQlObjectType
thanks for attention

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `GraphQlObjectType is not a constructor` error because of a typo, change it to [GraphQLObjectType](https://graphql.org/graphql-js/type/#graphqlobjecttype).